# Why we have to use a getter here for 'uppercasedFullName'?

Tags: lightning-web-components

Html->

```
<p class="slds-m-top_medium">
                Uppercased Full Name: {uppercasedFullName}
</p>
```

JS->

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class TrackExample extends LightningElement {
    firstName = '';
    lastName = '';

    handleChange(event) {
        const field = event.target.name;
        if (field === 'firstName') {
            this.firstName = event.target.value;
        } else if (field === 'lastName') {
            this.lastName = event.target.value;
        }
    }

    get uppercasedFullName() {
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`.trim().toUpperCase();
    }
    /***
        Why we can't use this->
        uppercasedFullname= this.firstname.toUpperCase() + ' ' + this.lastname.toUpperCase();
    ***/

}
```

Comment: Please use the `{}` tool in the editor, or wrap code in ``` (triple backticks) to ensure your code inclusions are formatted and visible to the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be:

```
this.uppercasedFullName = `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`.trim().toUpperCase();
```

You *can* do this, but then you need to remember to do it every time you update either field:

```
handleChange(event) {
    const field = event.target.name;
    if (field === 'firstName') {
        this.firstName = event.target.value;
    } else if (field === 'lastName') {
        this.lastName = event.target.value;
    }
    this.uppercasedFullName = `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`.trim().toUpperCase();
}
```

This is acceptable for small projects, but could be cumbersome in large projects. Using a getter as a "calculated value" makes sure that you don't miss any places where the value may change. However, for this project, it isn't necessary.

Also, you could have written a more compact event handler:

```
handleChange(event) {
    this[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
}
```

This would be a more typical way to do this, since it is dynamic, as well as a lot less code.